# While playing a WAV file of 192Khz sampling rate(which is not supported in android),the next song playback does not start

Tags: android

first of all,192KHZ sampling rate itself is not supported in android...hence,while we try play the file,either "The player doesn't support this type of file" message will be notified to user or the next song in the playlist will start playing automatically.

I fixed this issue in WAVExtractor by handling the maximum & minimum sampling rate that can be handled by our resampler. The fix works perfectly fine.but,the fix needs to be generic.

What i want to know is that .."who takes care of skipping an unsupported format & going to the next file and playing it??" is it the mediaplayer app which takes this decision based on the appropriate message it receives from the middleware level?

There can be multiple ways to declare a file "unsupported" in android.one such is the "Sampling Rate" constraint. Where exactly is the "Skipping" of a unsupported format & going to the next song handled?